# Left recursion for LL(1)

Tags: formal-languages, parsing, left-recursion

Hi I am trying to solve a LL(1) form question for first n follow rule The question is

```
A::=BC|C
B::=Bd|ef
C::=gh|j
```

What I have done to eliminate left recursion

```
A::=CA’
A’::=CB’
A’::=ϵ
B::=efB’
B::=dB’
B’::=ϵ
C::=gh
C::= j
```

Is it correct?

Thanks guys, it has been solved.

Comment: This question appears to be unsuited for this site because questions of the form: "This is the exercise problem, this is my solution. Please grade!" are not interesting for anyone but you. Please see [this related meta discussion](http://meta.cs.stackexchange.com/q/597/). If you want to ask a *specific* question about a *specific* part of your attempt, please edit the question accordingly and it may be reopened. Otherwise, you might want to visit [chat] and get some feedback there.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The only left-recursive rule is the one for $B$. The nonterminal $A$ produces no problems, $\operatorname{first}(B) = \{ e \}$ while $\operatorname{first}(C) = \{ g, j \}$. So you need to eliminate left recursion for $B$:

\begin{align}
B  &::= e f B' \\
B' &::= d B' \mid \epsilon
\end{align}

Comment: So the question is right then what would be first(A)?? It would be first(B)+first(C) ??

Comment: $\operatorname{first}(A) = \operatorname{first}(BC) \cup \operatorname{first}(C) = \operatorname{first}(B) \cup \operatorname{first}(C) = \{d, e, g, h \}$

Comment: confused. as first(B)={e} while first(C)={g,j}  then where does {d,h} comes from

Comment: Messed up, sorry (can't edit a comment and see the question)

Comment: so it should be First(A) = {e,g,j} right?

Comment: Please consider not to encourage [undesirable posting behaviour](http://meta.cs.stackexchange.com/q/597/).